# TouchableOpacity does not trigger onPress

Tags: react-native

For some reason I am not able to handle onPress from a TouchableOpacity, I've tried both on Android and IOS just to be sure that was not a platform specific problem. What is wrong with my component?

```
    import React,{Component} from 'react'
    import {Text,FlatList,TouchableOpacity,View} from 'react-native'

    const MenuMainScreenListItem = (props) => {


        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:'green'}} onPress={() => {
                console.log('xxx')
            }}>
                <View  style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
                    <Text>
                        {props.name}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }

    const MenuMainScreen  = (props) =>{

        let options = [
             {name:'name 1'}
            ,{name:'name 2'}
            ,{name:'name 3'}
            ,{name:'name 4'}
        ]

        return  (
            <View>
                {options.map((item, index) => {
                    return (<MenuMainScreenListItem key={index} name={item.key}/>)
                })}
            </View>

        )
    }

    export default MenuMainScreen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code in [React Native Website](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html) by putting your code. The only problem I met is `<MenuMainScreenListItem key={index} name={item.key}/>` should be `<MenuMainScreenListItem key={index} name={item.name}/>`. The TouchableOpacity working fine.